# How to get variable id in $(variable).click, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple images in a folder that I open directly on my page. 
The problem is I want to get the id of these generated images, because each image has a specific style in css (height, width, margin-top etc). With this id I want to place them on my page on different area.

I want to get a variable id in $(variable).click, if it's possible.

From this line I generate images

```
$("#bgaff1").append("<img src='" + dir + filename + "' class='elm' id='"+item+"'>");
```

In out in the HTML code I have  :

```
<img src="./img/catone/picture7.png" class="elm" id="picture7">
```

With this code I can only get the `class="elm"`, I don't know how to get the generated id by `item` variable

```
$('.elm').click(function(){
    var pict1= document.getElementById("pict1"); 
    pict1.src= dir + filename;
});
```

I already tried this :

```
$('.elm').click(function(){
    var pict1= document.getElementById("pict1"); pict1.src= dir + filename;
    var pict2= document.getElementById("pict2"); pict2.src= dir + filename;
});
```

But this code put the same style on the both images while they don't the same id. That's why I want to force the `$('.elm')` by the unique id of the pictures `#pict1`, `#pict2`... to handle each image with one different action.

Thank you for any help.

You can find the the ajax code here :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.categorie').click(function() {
    var dir = ($(this).attr('value'));
    var fileextension = ".png";

    $.ajax({
      //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
      url: dir,
      success: function(data) {
        //List all .png file names in the page
        $('#bgaff1').empty();

        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function() {
          var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
          var item = filename.replace('/', '').replace('.png', '');
          $("#bgaff1").append("<img src='" + dir + filename + "' class='elm' id='" + item + "'>");
          var filen = filename.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").replace('/', '').replace('.png', '');
          $('.elm').click(function() {
            var pict1 = document.getElementById("pict1");
            pict1.src = dir + filename;

          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Use an instance of `this`  - `$('.elm').click(function(){ console.log(this.id) });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of tring to find the generated id you can work with the class with this operation

```
$('.elm').click(function(){
  $(this).attr("src","_link_");
});
```

Above code will put the desired value to the clicked image.

Even still if you want find the current elements id, use following

```
$('.elm').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Comment: Please, use `this.id` instead!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `this.id` to get the element's ID, and similarly use `.src` to set the URL:

```
$('.elm').on('click', function() {
    var id = this.id;

    ...
    this.src = dir + filename;
});
```